# Cypress extract value of the input field and assign it to a variable

Tags: cypress

I want to assign a value of the input field to a variable but seems like it's not working for me can someone please help me to achieve this?

```js
let username;
cy.get("[id='dto.username']").invoke('val').then(val => {
        username = val;
        cy.log('username identified: ' + username); // this displays correctly
        return username;
    });

cy.log('Returned username :' + username); // this doesn't contain a value it's undefined
```

I'm trying to assign it to a variable because I have to send an API request outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
it('Test Case One', () => {

   let username;

    cy.get("[id='dto.username']").invoke('val').then(val => {
        username = val
    }).then(() => {
        // send the request here using the `username` variable
        cy.log('Username: ' + username);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to apply a `.then()` to see this code work.

```js
let username;
cy.get("[id='dto.username']").invoke('val').then(val => {
        username = val;
        cy.log('username identified: ' + username); // this displays correctly
        return username;
    });

cy.then(() => {
  cy.log('Returned username :' + username);  // this now displays correctly

  cy.request({body: username, ...})
})
```

The reason is your final log takes it's parameter before the query commands are run (when `username` is `undefined`).

By wrapping the command in `cy.then()` you defer taking the parameter value until the variable has been set by the preceding code.

You can also chain the `.then()` if you want,

```js
let username;
cy.get("[id='dto.username']").invoke('val')
  .then(val => {
        username = val;
        cy.log('username identified: ' + username); // this displays correctly
        return username;
   })
  .then(() => {
    cy.log('Returned username :' + username);  // this now displays correctly

    cy.request({body: username, ...})
  })
```

Comment: Now it's throwing this error. 
```
cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().

The value you synchronously returned was: 
```